# SharePoint Workflow 2013 always Suspended showing System.IO.InvalidDataException

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I am having this issue in SP Workflow 2013 that every time it executed , it always goes to Suspended stage.

However, I do not have any HTTP calls in the workflow. Its just getting current item value. Refer below.

[image]

> RequestorId: 6ad701cc-759b-fdb1-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to
>   deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType :
>   'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType
>   : 'text/html'. Content (truncated) : ' '.
>   ResponseStatusCode : 'OK' Request Uri :
>   'https://website.com/sub/subsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.ResolvePrincipalInCurrentcontext(input=@ParamUser,scopes='15',sources='15',inputIsEmailOnly='false',addToUserInfoList='False')?@ParamUser='i:0%23.w|group\sakthi''
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Kindly assist

Cheers,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache, then recreate the worklfow, compare the results.

Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx

Comment: I have cleared the cache and it doesn't works. still showing same error